# Identifying the most relavant document in a information retrieval system

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, search-engine, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I am developing a search engine modeled after google in my spare time.

I am using the original google research paper located at http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html as my guideline.

As i am developing a very very simplified version of google i am not using pagerank algorithm at all for now.

So far i have developed a simple parser and indexer whose result is that i have an inverted index containing number of hits, hit location and document hash against each unique word.

Now i am trying to develop a query engine. However i am finding it hard to identify the most relevant document for a multi token query.

Specifically lets say i am having difficulty in calculating the proximity of the query words to each other in a document.

I have thought of a algorithm that scans each document for the query words and calculates the proximity score based on how much the query words are close to each other however i suspect this would take a long time, and i think there is a better way to do this of which i am not aware and the research paper is too general to get an answer.

I am just looking for a pointer in the right direction.

Any sort of help would be very very very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the inverted index section of "Search Engine Indexing" on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#Inverted_indices

Basically, you want to save the position information of a given word within a document, this makes it easy to compute proximity. This information is saved in the index.

The key point is to *index* your documents so you don't need to scan them every time. The search for keywords is done on the index that points to the documents containing those keywords.

P.S. don't forget that you're trying to keep the index as small as possible, so storing gaps or differences for word positions will save same memory (as explained in: [J. Zobel, A. Moffat - Inverted Files for Search Text Engines](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~jz/fulltext/compsurv06.pdf) at page 23).